# Align String Array to Columns

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a String Array that contains some names in it.
I want to show the names in my console with string column alignment.
For example this is my array:

`{"First","Second","Third","Forth","Fifth","Sixth","Seventh","Eighth","Ninth"};`

And then display them in this format:

```
First       Second      Third
Forth       Fifth       Sixth
Seventh     Eighth      Ninth
```

As you see these names are aligned in columns with spaces between them, that's what I want. How to do that?

Comment: Do you want your columns to be of adaptable width?

Comment: @ZoranHorvat yes if it's possible

Comment: That would complicate matters a lot because you cannot tell up-front how many columns you can fit onto the screen. You would have to reiterate the algorithm for several numbers of columns before a viable solution can be found.

Comment: @ZoranHorvat isn't possible to create something like `LS` command is commandlines ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string[] str={"First","Second","Third","Forth","Fifth","Sixth","Seventh","Eighth","Ninth"};
    for (int i=0;i<str.Length-2;i+=3)
    Console.WriteLine ("{0,-10}   {1,-10}   {2,-10}",str[i],str[i+1],str[i+2]);
```

Demo Code

> https://repl.it/repls/CelebratedMuffledCybernetics

Comment: This really is a hard coded answer, but sticks to the question. So, upvote!

Comment: Thanks @FarhanQasim

Comment: Welcome @AI00X :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have expressed the desire to have full adaptability of column widths, then below is the entire solution. As I said, it won't be easy at all.

This solution supports words of any length (not longer than the screen width). The result is always the screen populated as densely as possible, given the text.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static IEnumerable<(string value, int row, int col)> Break(IEnumerable<string> data, int columnsNumber) =>
            data.Select((item, index) => (item, index / columnsNumber, index % columnsNumber));

        static IEnumerable<int> GetColumnWidths(IEnumerable<string> data, int columnsNumber) =>
            Break(data, columnsNumber)
                .GroupBy(tuple => tuple.col)
                .Select(group => group.Max(tuple => tuple.value.Length));

        static int RequiredScreenWidth(IEnumerable<string> data, int columnsNumber) =>
            GetColumnWidths(data, columnsNumber)
                .Sum() + columnsNumber - 1;

        static int SuggestNumberOfColumns(IEnumerable<string> data, int screenWidth) =>
            Enumerable.Range(1, int.MaxValue)
                .TakeWhile(columnsNumber => RequiredScreenWidth(data, columnsNumber) <= screenWidth)
                .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
                .Last();

        static IEnumerable<string> Pad(IEnumerable<string> data, int columnsNumber, int[] columnWidths) =>
            Break(data, columnsNumber)
                .Select(tuple => (tuple.value.PadRight(columnWidths[tuple.col], ' ')));

        static IEnumerable<string> GenerateRows(IEnumerable<string> paddedData, int columnsNumber) =>
            Break(paddedData, columnsNumber)
                .GroupBy(tuple => tuple.row)
                .Select(row => string.Join(" ", row.Select(tuple => tuple.value).ToArray()));

        static string GenerateColumnatedText(IEnumerable<string> paddedData, int columnsNumber) =>
            string.Join(Environment.NewLine, GenerateRows(paddedData, columnsNumber).ToArray());

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> data = new[]
            {
                "Over", "time", "the", ".NET", "Framework", "has", "added", "many",
                "features", "that", "made", "concurrent", "programming", "a", "lot",
                "easier", "This", "started", "with", "the", "introduction", "of",
                "the", "thread", "pool", "got", "a", "lot", "more", "powerful", "with",
                "the", "task-based", "model", "and", "the", "Task", "Parallel",
                "Library", "and", "was", "improved", "even", "more", "by", "the",
                "addition", "of", "the", "async", "and", "await", "language",
                "keywords", "While", "creating", "and", "running", "concurrently",
                "is", "easier", "than", "ever", "one", "of", "the", "fundamental",
                "problems", "still", "exists", "mutable", "shared", "state", "Reading",
                "from", "multiple", "threads", "is", "typically", "very", "easy", "but",
                "once", "the", "state", "needs", "to", "be", "updated", "it", "gets",
                "a", "lot", "harder", "especially", "in", "designs", "that", "require",
                "locking", "An", "alternative", "to", "locking", "is", "making", "use",
                "of", "immutable", "state", "Immutable", "data", "structures", "are",
                "guaranteed", "to", "never", "change", "and", "can", "thus", "be",
                "passed", "freely", "between", "different", "threads", "without",
                "worrying", "about", "stepping", "on", "somebody", "else’s", "toes"
            };

            int columnsNumber = SuggestNumberOfColumns(data, 80);
            int[] columnWidths = GetColumnWidths(data, columnsNumber).ToArray();
            IEnumerable<string> padded = Pad(data, columnsNumber, columnWidths);
            string text = GenerateColumnatedText(padded, columnsNumber);

            Console.WriteLine(text);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When applied to the text from the demo, and to the screen of 60 characters wide, the result is a perfectly aligned order of columns:

```
Over         time        the         .NET         Framework
has          added       many        features     that
made         concurrent  programming a            lot
easier       This        started     with         the
introduction of          the         thread       pool
got          a           lot         more         powerful
with         the         task-based  model        and
the          Task        Parallel    Library      and
was          improved    even        more         by
the          addition    of          the          async
and          await       language    keywords     While
creating     and         running     concurrently is
easier       than        ever        one          of
the          fundamental problems    still        exists
mutable      shared      state       Reading      from
multiple     threads     is          typically    very
easy         but         once        the          state
needs        to          be          updated      it
gets         a           lot         harder       especially
in           designs     that        require      locking
An           alternative to          locking      is
making       use         of          immutable    state
Immutable    data        structures  are          guaranteed
to           never       change      and          can
thus         be          passed      freely       between
different    threads     without     worrying     about
stepping     on          somebody    else's       toes
```

Answer (score -1):

Sample Example

```
     string[] val = { "First", "Second", "Third", "Forth", "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh", "Eighth", "Ninth" };
        for (int i = 0,j=1;  i < val.Length  ; i++) {

            Console.Write("{0}   ", val[i]);

            if (j % 3 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            j++;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use add tabs to your string when printing them on screen with `WriteLine` using `\t` escape sequence.

For example if you are printing 3 string on screen, you can do it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("String 1" + "\t"
    + "String 2" + "\t" 
    + "String 3");
```

Comment: each string characters could differ to each other, so this is not my answer